# How running a mta with exim on centos?

Tags: centos, centos5, exim, dovecot, email-server

I'm try learning run a MTA with virtual domains and exim from 2 weeks ago.
but now, I can not do any thing. i select exim for mta and dovecot for imap daemon. but i can not run them, i can not understand how dovecot works and etc. i can not find a straight document.

Can you offer a straight document to start?

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with the [Dovecot documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/)?

Comment: i see this document, but i can't find a good document for exim after that i want to work with dovecot. i want run exim to handle virtual domains. i read some of exim.org/docs.html docs but can not understand it good. i want to know were i should start from?

Comment: And what is wrong with the Exim documentation?

Comment: i read some section of that documents, but i don't understand it. i have a problem that if i send an email from gmail to my mat i can't find it's problem before more than 24 h that i receive an email that contain problem such as, bad dns, or can't find acc. also i should stay more than 6 hour to change dns, etc. i say, is not there any tutorial to config virtual domain and dovecot on centos with exim?

Comment: Ali, looks to me that your problem is not exim or dovecot, rather the internetworking architecture and the way it relates to email. You should read up on DNS, mail protocols and such. O'Reilly has several such books. That'll take a few months. Or, hire a sysadmin.

Comment: +1 for "read up on stuff". Trying to hook these things together without having a clue about how they work is asking for trouble. These aren't simple things, they're complex pieces of software.